# Error : Binary operator '-=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int?' and 'Int'

Tags: ios, swift

This similar question has been asked many time on S.O. But still I've didn't received any solution for this. I'm very new to iOS. So plz let me know whether I'm doing any mistake over here..???

**Note :** I'm converting Swift 2.3 - Swift 3.2 using Xcode 8

```
func dateFourHoursBack() -> Date {
    let today = Date()

    let calendar = Calendar.current
    var components = (calendar as NSCalendar).components([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second] , from: today)
    components.hour -= 4 //Error : Binary operator '-=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int?' and 'Int

    return calendar.date(from: components)!
}
```

Plz help me...

Comment: What about `components.hour! -= 4`

Comment: Unrelated to the error, but there's no need to cast `calendar` to `NSCalendar`, you should simply do `calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second] , from: today)`.

Comment: Oh...!! Thanks @DávidPásztor

Comment: @schtipoun. we should avoid force unwrapping becuase if there is no value, app will crash.

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz for sure! It's just that I don't have the rest of the code so I assume there's an `if let` or something similar to make it work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bad conversion. Don't use `NSCalendar` in Swift 3+.

The error says that you cannot apply the `-=` operator to an optional.

Unlike Swift 2 in Swift 3+ all date components are optional but if the unit is specified in the `dateComponents(...` line you can safely force unwrap it.

```
func dateFourHoursBack() -> Date {
    let today = Date()

    let calendar = Calendar.current
    var components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second] , from: today)
    components.hour! -= 4    
    return calendar.date(from: components)!
}
```

By the way there is a more convenient method

```
func dateFourHoursBack() -> Date {
    return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: -4, to: Date())!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because `components.hour` is an optional value. you have to check for nil OR, force unwrap it using `!` operator if you are 100% sure it will contain a value.

Good practice is to avoid force unwrapping using `!`  operator and play safe. Like this

```
if let hours = components.hour {
  //do your stuff here 
}
```

Comment: In this particular case ***you are 100% sure*** because you just passed the `.hour` unit.

Comment: Thanks @AwaisFayyaz

Comment: Got it Sir @vadian